# Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in line

Tags: php

I am a PHP newbie and I am getting two notices on a code that is part of a gallery, can you help me figure this out? Notices are

> > Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/raj/public_html/viewgallery.php on line 408
> >       Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/raj/public_html/viewgallery.php on line 426

Line 408 is

```
    'pcaption' => $caption_array[$next]);
```

And line 426 is

```
$result_final.= '<div class="limage"><table><tr><td><table class="image"><tr><td><a href="photos/'.$cname.'/'.$caption_array[$next].'/'.$q.'/"><img src="' . $images_dir . '/' . $photo_filename . '"  alt=" ' . $photo_keywords . '"></a><div class="caption">' . $photo_caption . '</div><div class="excerpt">' . $photo_description . '</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="underline"></div></div>'.$backString.'</div>';
```

The above lines are part of this code...

```
$next = 0;
$prev = 0;
if ($ct > 1)
{


$key = array_search($pcaption, $caption_array);
$prev = $key - 1;
if ($prev < 0) $prev = $ct - 1;
$next = $key + 1;
$searchNext = $key + 1;


if ($next == $ct) $next = 0;
$total_count = count($caption_array);
$result_final.= "<div id='prevnext'>";
$parameters_next = array(
'cname' => $cname,
'pcaption' => $caption_array[$next]
);
$parameters_prev = array(
'cname' => $cname,
'pcaption' => $caption_array[$prev]
);


$categoryNamePrev = $cname;
$photoCaptionNext = $caption_array[$next];
$photoCaptionPrev = $caption_array[$prev];



if($q !='' && $searchNext==$ct ) {

    $previousUrl = 'photos/'.$categoryNamePrev.'/'.$photoCaptionPrev.'/'.$q.'/';
    $nextUrl = '/searchmyway.php?q='.$q.'&form_id%3Asearch=1';
} else {

    if($q != '') {
        $previousUrl = 'photos/'.$categoryNamePrev.'/'.$photoCaptionPrev.'/'.$q.'/';
        $nextUrl = 'photos/'.$categoryNamePrev.'/'.$photoCaptionNext.'/'.$q.'/';
    } else {
        $previousUrl = 'photos/'.$categoryNamePrev.'/'.$photoCaptionPrev.'/';
        $nextUrl = 'photos/'.$categoryNamePrev.'/'.$photoCaptionNext.'/';
    }   
}


$result_final.= '<span class="prev"><a href="'.$previousUrl.'"><img src="/photos/assets/left.png" alt="left navigation"></a></span>';
$result_final.= '<span class="next"><a href="'.$nextUrl.'"><img src="/photos/assets/right.png" alt="right navigation"></a></span>';
$result_final.= "</div>";
}
}

$key = array_search($pcaption, $caption_array);
$prev = $key - 1;
if ($prev < 0) $prev = $ct - 1;
$next = $key + 1;
$searchNext = $key + 1;
$parameters_next = array(
'cname' => $cname,
'pcaption' => $caption_array[$next]
);
$parameters_prev = array(
'cname' => $cname,
'pcaption' => $caption_array[$prev]
);

if($q != '') {
        $backString = '<a href="/searchmyway.php?q='.$q.'&form_id%3Asearch=1">Back</a>';
} else {
$backString  = '';
}


if($q == '') {
$result_final.= '<div class="limage"><table><tr><td><table class="image"><tr><td><a href="photos/'.$cname.'/'.$caption_array[$next].'/"><img src="' . $images_dir . '/' . $photo_filename . '"  alt=" ' . $photo_keywords . '"></a><div class="caption">' . $photo_caption . '</div><div class="excerpt">' . $photo_description . '</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="underline"></div></div>'.$backString.'</div>';
} else  {
$result_final.= '<div class="limage"><table><tr><td><table class="image"><tr><td><a href="photos/'.$cname.'/'.$caption_array[$next].'/'.$q.'/"><img src="' . $images_dir . '/' . $photo_filename . '"  alt=" ' . $photo_keywords . '"></a><div class="caption">' . $photo_caption . '</div><div class="excerpt">' . $photo_description . '</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><div class="underline"></div></div>'.$backString.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: `$caption_array` does not have element with index 3

Comment: Thanks Cheery, but can you explain this a bit more? Sorry I am very new at this.

Comment: Your `$next` variable is equal to 3 and you are using it as a key/index in `$caption_array[$next]`, but array `$caption_array` does not have element with index = 3. That is why php throws this notice, that you are trying to get the value of non-existent element of array.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when the element you find is in the last element, the "next" element doesn't exist, and when you try to use it, it gives you the notice.

At least, that's what I understand from your code.

Maybe an:

```
if($next<$total_count)
```

would help?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for helping me. I solved this problem by initializing the variable and array, `$caption_array[$next]=array();` no more notices. Thanks again..